# Arranging side by side images in html using CSS?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I'm trying achieve a way to display my images in a particular layout using CSS. I can't figure how I can do this using CSS.

I'm placing two small images on top of each other and one tall one on the right alongside the small images, the tall image has height equal to the small photos.

**Required layout:**

```
┌─────────────┬────────────┐
│ SMALL IMAGE │            │
├─────────────| TALL IMAGE |
│ SMALL IMAGE │            │
└─────────────┴────────────┘
```

my code is on jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/VjfGS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired output with minimal markup changes: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/AzyQG

**HTML:**

```
<div class ="image-section">
    <img class="tall" src ="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Lifeandhealth/Pix/pictures/2009/3/5/1236251569000/Six-gorgeous-plants-Close-001.jpg" width="60px" height="180px">
    <img src ="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Lifeandhealth/Pix/pictures/2009/3/5/1236251569000/Six-gorgeous-plants-Close-001.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"> 
    <img src ="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Lifeandhealth/Pix/pictures/2009/3/5/1236251569000/Six-gorgeous-plants-Close-001.jpg" width="120px" height="90px">
</div>
<div class ="image-section"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tall {
    float: right;
}
img {
    float: left;
}
.image-section{
    width: 180px;
}​
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5kxNm/

CSS:

```
.tall {
    float: none;
}
img {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}​
```

WARNING: This is a "quick-n-dirty" fix and might not work in all situations!!

Comment: That's to dirty; consider the other answers for a better way

Answer (score 0):

For example, like this http://jsfiddle.net/VjfGS/4/

```
<div class ="image-section">
    <div class="left">
        <img> 
        <img>
    </div>
    <img class="tall">
</div>
<div class ="image-section"></div>
​.tall {
    float:left;
}
.left{
    float: left;
}
.left img{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this'll do it

http://jsfiddle.net/VjfGS/18/

```
<div class ="image-section">
    <div class="smallDiv">    
         <img src ="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Lifeandhealth/Pix/pictures/2009/3/5/1236251569000/Six-gorgeous-plants-Close-001.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"> <br/>
          <img src ="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Lifeandhealth/Pix/pictures/2009/3/5/1236251569000/Six-gorgeous-plants-Close-001.jpg" width="120px" height="90px">
    </div>
    <img class="tall" src ="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Lifeandhealth/Pix/pictures/2009/3/5/1236251569000/Six-gorgeous-plants-Close-001.jpg" width="60px" height="180px">
</div>
<div class ="image-section"></div>

.smallDiv{
    float:left;
}
```

​